# Multiple rows from Left Join in SQL were rows are uniquely matched

Tags: sql, left-join

I have two views that I am trying to join. I am joining on three elements, date, case number and surgeon id number. Each should only have one match for the previous case out value, but I am getting multiple rows after my left join.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[OR]
AS
     SELECT DISTINCT 
         [ID].*,
         [BYSURG].[PREV_PAT_OUT] AS PrevPtOut
     FROM
         [dbo].[OR_LOG_INDEXED] [ID]    
     LEFT JOIN 
         [DBO].[OR_CASE_NUM] BYSURG ON [ID].[SURG_DT] = [BYSURG].[SURG_DT]
                                    AND [ID].[SURGEON_ID] = [BYSURG].[SURGEON_ID]
                                    AND [ID].[CASE_NUM_BY_ROOM] = [BYSURG].[CASE_NUM_BY_ROOM_ADJ]
```

Any insights are much appreciated.

Thanks!

M

Comment: You’ll need to include sample data to get a good answer, but most likely is that those three values aren’t unique in at least some cases for those two tables.

Comment: Hil You are not clearly describing what output you want in terms of input & you have not given relevant constraints or even example in put & output & desired output. Please act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Replace your select block with one that retrieves all columns:

```
 SELECT  
     *
 FROM
     [dbo].[OR_LOG_INDEXED] [ID]    
 LEFT JOIN 
     [DBO].[OR_CASE_NUM] BYSURG ON [ID].[SURG_DT] = [BYSURG].[SURG_DT]
                                AND [ID].[SURGEON_ID] = [BYSURG].[SURGEON_ID]
                                AND [ID].[CASE_NUM_BY_ROOM] = [BYSURG].[CASE_NUM_BY_ROOM_ADJ]
```

Run it and look at your "duplicate" rows - something about them will no longer be a duplicate - perhaps you've forgotten to include some other criteria in your where clause

Putting DISTINCT in the select block is not the answer - find out what data element about the "duplicate" rows is different and then filter out the rows you don't want